# Can i shift my subject from Chemistry to IT

Tags: education

I have completed my gradation in leather engineering. But i would like to do M.Sc in Information Technology or Software Engineering or computer science or bio medical engineering or bio engineering.
I am working in software firm as well as freelance software developer. I have one software related publication & other two  environmental chemistry related publication. But now i'm really enjoying software development & i would like to do my M.Sc/PhD in these subject .As i wont like to do anything that actually i don't like. But will university accept me if my would like to shift myself from chemistry background to IT?

Comment: I actually know a large number of PhD chemists working in CompSci -- myself among them!

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can!  Especially since you have an IT related publication and it seems you have shown interest in the field. I would highly recommend finding a supervisor with a project that appeals to you. It's all about your relationship with them for a positive graduate experience. If they want you and have funding for you, you will have much better chances of getting into the school you want to work on a project that excites you.